# removing specific value from a string jq

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var delivery_nums = ($("#delivery_num").val()).split(",");
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

for (var num =0 ; num < delivery_nums.length ; num++ ) {

   var input = '<div class="delivery-num-input">';
   input += "<input type='text'  pattern='[0-9]+'\
             class='form-control delivery_number_plus'\
             value='delivery_nums[num]'\
             placeholder='ex(1524587....)' required/>\
             <a href='#' class='remove_field btn btn-sm btn-danger'>\
             Remove</a></div>";
   $(wrapper).append(input); //add input box
```

}

the value of delivery_nums as ['9999999', '888888', '55555555'] it's not array it's as string so i made split to make it as array as :

```
 ['9999999'
 '888888'
'55555555']
```

i want to remove this [ and  ] and '' to be an array

Comment: "...i want to remove this [ ] and '' to be an array..." - hard to understand what do You want

Comment: That is an array - you can tell because the `[` and `]` are outside the string delimiters, although it would help if you gave clearer examples of your input and output strings

Comment: The `'` identify the data as type `string`., and the `[ ]` show that the string data is kept in an `array`. Are you wanting 3 numbers of type `integer`?

Comment: if  ['9999999', '888888', '55555555'] is literally waht you start with, its already an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just use `.split(",")` on the string it will keep `[,], and '` characters too, so you need to remove them before using `split()`:

```js
var x = "['9999999', '888888', '55555555']";
x = x.replace(/[\[\]' ]/g, '');
console.log(x);
var arr = x.split(",");
console.log(arr);
```

And the array values will be just numbers wrapped in strings if you want to get them as numbers you can use `Number()` or `parseInt()` like this:

```
arr = arr.map(function(el){
  return Number(el);
});
```

Or just:

```
arr = arr.map(Number);
```

Comment: thank u it works i have another question in code if u see value='delivery_nums[num]'\ it's printed as it i want to make it as variable that shows me 99999 on input value and 8888 and so on what should i do ?

Comment: in your last sample I would to set 
`arr = arr.map(Number)`

Comment: @zb' Thank you, yes it would be better ;)

Comment: @marwam you need to change your logic and use JS to create these elements, ` var input = document.createElement("input"); input.type="text"; input.pattern = "[0-9]+"` then `input.value = delivery_nums[num]`, this way you will avoid using too much escaping and manage the variables better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) String.prototype.replace and [Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) constructor

```js
var input = "['9999999', '888888', '55555555']";
var result = input.split(',')
   .map(value => Number(value.replace(/\D/g,''))).join(',');
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Well it's a nice approach too!